# CSS and specificity - class vs ids

Tags: css, class, css-specificity, text-decorations

Consider the following html:

```
<div id="rightBar">
    <div class="barElement">
        <div class="barText"><a href="#">Not underlined</a><br /></div>
        <div class="barLinks"><a href="#">Should be underlined</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following css:

```
#rightBar a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
#rightBar a.barLinks
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

The 'Should be underlined' link is not underlined, shouldn't it be since it inherits both the class barLinks and the id rightbar. Also the '#rightBar a.barLinks' (0, 1, 1, 1) has more specificity than '#rightBar a' (0, 1, 0, 1), so it should override the latter right?

How else can I get the 'Should be underlined' link to be underlined without resorting to using any inline specifications (both css or html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `a` element does not have the class `barLinks`. Do this:

```
#rightBar .barLinks a
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/J34mj/2/

Comment: yes, I agree this. `#rightBar a.barLinks` means only those `a` tags which have class attribute set to `barLinks` i.e. `<a class='barLinks' ...`

Answer (score 2):

It's not a specificity issue, you are using the wrong selector. It should be this:

```
#rightBar .barLinks a {}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#rightBar a.barLinks
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Won't work because the class="barLinks" isn't on the `<a>`

Try this;

```
#rightBar .barLinks a
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Or failing that;

```
#rightBar .barLinks a
{
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be, the barLinks is only applicable to a tags, if you change your css to #rightBar .barLinks a it should work.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem I see here is that you have mentioned an incorrect address to reach to your anchor tag element using the CSS selector. If you are going for a longer and more prominent address route then it should be as follows:

```
#rightbar .barElement .barLinks a{
    text-decoration : underline;
}
```

But since you are looking for a more specific one, your approach was correct except for the fact the anchor tag does not have a class of its own, therefore a.barLink would find nothing. It should rather be as :

```
#rightBar .barLinks a{
text-decoration : underline;
}
```